2018 Kia Sportage won't stay on
2018 Kia Sportage - New Fuel pump, new spark plugs, new throttle body and the car will still not stay going unless you have your foot on the gas pedal...No vacuum leaks transmission seems fine. I am going to replace the pedal sensor on sat. Please someone help me.

Could make a lot of guesses, but if you told us the trouble codes it would help tremendously.

p0122 Code P0455 code The Evap code came on and went off. There is no leak.
Other than those 2 codes it hasn't thrown anymore. When the Fuel Pump went out the machine didn't come up with any codes. It was after replacing things that the codes showed finally.

Before throwing more parts (money) into this you might want to solve existing problems first. First make sure there is not a relearn procedure required to the TPS. Many vehicles require a relearn when changing the TPS and\or throttle body. If the relearn doesn't work, use a scanner in the TPS PID, check the sweep of the position sensor. I could keep giving you diagnosing steps for quite a while, but you need to have your TPS and wiring checked out.
